# Ubuntu will not boot without acpi=off

Tags: boot, dual-boot, acpi

I have a new  HP Zbook G5 studio laptop and it had preinstalled Windows in it. I wanted to set up a dual boot with Ubuntu (and I have used Kubuntu). I installed through a live USB, but in order to boot the live USB I found that I needed to use the flag `acpi=off`.
I did manage to install Kubuntu this way, but since acpi is off I don't have any indication about the battery and the brightness and perhaps other things that I didn't notice.

I have currently deleted the installation of Ubuntu and reverted everything as before, so I have only Windows installed.

Here is a screen photo of the screen during boot having removed the flag `quiet` from grub and not using `acpi=off`.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question after quite some time. The solution comes from [this](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1057728/linux/nvrm-xid-pci-0000-01-00-79-gpu-has-fallen-off-the-bus-hp-studio-g5/) topic in the Nvidia Forums. The issue apparently is some problem with the cstates. The use of `intel_idle.max_cstate=1` fixed it for me!

Answer (score 1):

I also have an hp zbook studio g5 x360 which I've been struggling to get things working in Ubuntu (also tried Mint). To get it to boot, at the grub boot menu, remove `quiet splash` and replace with `nomodeset`. This allowed me to boot and install Ubuntu.

Some other issues you may run into:

- Display resolution issue (I have the 4k screen): Manually install Nvidia drivers
- Touchpad not working: I have not been able to resolve this yet but there are a couple kernel bugs filed that are related and one other question here on AskUbuntu about this that does not yet have a solution. One thing I have found as have others is that if you suspend Ubuntu and then wake it back up, the touchpad will partially work. I'm using a bluetooth or usb mouse until I get this resolved.
- Display brightness can't be adjusted in settings: The only thing I found for this is to install xbacklight ( `sudo apt-get install xbacklight` ) and use that to control the brightness percentage ( `xbacklight 20` )